# How to Transfer Domain from one Geodatabase to another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, domains

How do I transfer Domain to another .gdb in ArcGIS?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

You could export a featureclass that uses the domain from the original gdb to the new one and select transfer field domain descriptions from the 'Fields' section of Environments. The process is described in more detail here: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011973

Or you could use the "Domain To Table" tool (in ArcToolBox > Data Management Tools > Domains) to export the domain from the old gdb, then use the "Table To Domain" tool (located in the same toolbox as the previous tool) to load the domain into the new gdb.

Comment: I have tried the former approach and it didn't work for me. I tried both importing the feature class (from the new location) and exporting the feature class (from the original location), and neither brought the domains over.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ArcGIS Pro you can right click the original gdb in the catalog > domains.

Then click the domain that you are interested in highlighting the row. Then right-click the side of the table row > Copy.

Open up the new gdb table by right-clicking the gdb in the catalog > right click the side of the domains table > paste > save.

Answer (score 1):

I used the above ArcGIS Pro method and it worked perfectly.

Remember, to add a domain you have go to the Fields View of the attribute table, and use the Domain field to select an existing domain or create a new one.

Once I copied over the OG domains to the right geodatabase, I was able to choose them from the drop-down menu in the Domains column of the Fields View.

Comment: "Above" and "below" are not effective descriptions when each user can order the list as they see fit. To reduce confusion, be sure to reference by screen name.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste function in the Pro domain table doesn't work when attempting to copy domain matrix out of ArcGIS Pro into a txt or xls file. If this is the goal, you will need to use the geoprocessing tool to convert the domain to a table.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @AvidDabbler's answer:

(In ArcGIS Pro) Start by adding your domain, so it's available to reference if/when you add a new field.

1. Access the Domains interface either by:

- right-clicking source GDB in Catalog > Domains, or
- right-clicking source layer in table of contents > Data Design > Domains

2. Copy/paste domain(s) from source into target by right-clicking > Copy/Paste on the left side of the desired row in the domains interface (the bottom blank row in the case of the target). Save when done. New domains will be visible for selection.
3. If adding fields, repeat the above step for Fields instead of Domains. If done in this order, 'domains' should already be filled in. Save when done.